# Issue placing InfoWindows on Google Map markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to place multiple markers on a Google Map using JSON with InfoWindows bound to each marker. Unfortunately, only one marker appears, which is the last value in the JSON. No other marker will show and the  comic balloon-style arrow doesn't appear trailing from the InfoWindow. Have tried for quite a while to resolve this but nothing appears to work.

This is the code:

```
var stories = {{story_Json|safe}};

var map;


function loadMarkers(stories){
    for (i=0;i<stories.length;i++) {
        var story = stories[i];
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(story.latitude, story.longitude);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point, map: map});
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: '<div >'+
                '<div >'+
                '</div>'+
                '<h2 class="firstHeading">'+story.headline+'</h2>'+
                '<div>'+
                '<p>'+story.copy+'</p>'+

                '</div>'+
                '</div>'

        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });

    }
}


 function mainMap(position)
 {
       // Define the coordinates as a Google Maps LatLng Object
       var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

       // Prepare the map options
       var mapOptions =
      {
                  zoom: 15,
                  center: coords,
                  mapTypeControl: false,
                  navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        // Create the map, and place it in the map_canvas div
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

        // Place the initial marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: coords,
                  map: map,
                  title: "Your current location!"
        });

        loadMarkers(stories);

    }
```

Any insight into these issues much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InfoWindow is keeping a reference using the last value of i (since the loop ended, we see the last value of the JSON). This has to do with function scope in Javascript rather than block scope.

One way to get the desired results is to introduce a new `story` to reference each of the values of stories for each infowindow. This can be done with a new anonymous function scope:

```
function loadMarkers(stories){
    for (i=0;i<stories.length;i++) {
        var story = stories[i];

        (function(story) {
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(story.latitude, story.longitude);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point, map: map});
          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: '<div >'+
                '<div >'+
                '</div>'+
                '<h2 class="firstHeading">'+story.headline+'</h2>'+
                '<div>'+
                '<p>'+story.copy+'</p>'+

                '</div>'+
                '</div>'

          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,this);
          });
        })(story);
    }
}
```

Forgot about the infowindow arrow, is it displayed incorrectly, like blurred or deformed? Maybe it's a CSS thing, adding these lines may help you.

```
#map_canvas label { width: auto; display:inline; }
#map_canvas img { max-width: none; max-height: none; }
```

Comment: Thanks, Heitor. That seems to work. Can't close the infowindow but that's another question. The arrow is the only thing that isn't appearing, but I'll try the CSS solution. The arrow is just currently missing; not sure why.

Comment: If you don't see the x in the infowindows' top right corner, and you're unable to close it, this can be related to the balloon arrow not appearing. Are you using Wordpress or a CMS? I read about the google maps components deforming when used together with a CMS so I do encourage you to try the CSS fix and if it's ineffective I suggest posting an image.

Comment: No, I don't see the x. I'm using Django. Maybe that's related.

Comment: Just added the CSS snippets to the CSS file and – voila – it's working! Thanks, Heitor! Fantastic solutions!